# C# EXAM Conceptual guidance

Tags: c#

a question I cannot understand. The answer is b), but can someone tell me why?
I realize it is something between a) and b). But why b)? If the event raising method is public, then can't anyone raise the event?

You have declared an event on your class, and you want outside users of your class to raise this event. What do you do?
A.
Make the event public.
B.
Add a public method to your class that raises the event.
C.
Use a public delegate instead of an event.
D.
Use a custom event accessor to give access to outside users.

Comment: The question clearly states this: **and you want outside users of your class to raise the event**. So clearly, yes, anyone can raise it, and that answers the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an exam and the question is just a misread or missing thorough read of the question from the exam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question gives you two pieces of information:

> 1. You *have* declared an event on your class, and
> 2. you *want* outside users of your class to raise this event.

Now read the answers and see how they relate to the information given to you:

> a. Make the event public.

Does making an event public help users outside your class raise an event? No, it does not: it lets them listen to your event, but it does not let them raise the event.

> c. Use a public delegate instead of an event.

This is red herring: declaring a public delegate is part of declaring an event itself, so it does not help outside users raise an event.

> d. Use a custom event accessor to give access to outside users.

This is similar to answer `a`: giving users access to an event does not help them raise it.

> b. Add a public method to your class that raises the event.

This is the direct answer to the question: you wanted to let users raise an event, so you designed a method for doing precisely that.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you! Not only did this bring the obvious in front of me, but also offered me a problem solving strategy!

Answer (score 4):

The difference between a) and b) is that in C# -- by design / its specifications -- events can only be raised from the class that declares them, not code outside.

If you declare the event public, outside code will be able to subscribe / unsubscribe from the event. But not raise it. Trying to do so ends up with a compiler error.

So if you want outside code to raise an event, you should expose a public method that does just that.

c) is not a very good answer. It's similar to saying: expose a public field rather than a public property.

d) A custom accessor ({ add; remove; }) won't change anything to the situation.